# Invalid or corrupt sbt-launch-jar file

Tags: java, scala, jar, apache-spark, sbt

I have been trying to install spark on my MacOSX. I have already installed Scala and Sbt using brew. After downloading and untarring the spark-1.4.1 (i have also tried spark-1.2.1 and spark-1.1.1) I am running -

```
sbt/sbt clean assembly
```

Everytime its the same error:

```
Invalid or corrupt jarfile sbt/sbt-launch-0.13.5.jar
```

I have tried above mentioned solutions of changing the name and manually installing sbt, but none of those seems to work. I have seen people asking questions on stackoverflow lot of times and solution does not seem to be consistent. Can some one help me here?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yikes. If you look at the contents of this "jar" file, it's actually an HTML 404 document. I'll report a bug.

If you decide to build a distribution, the Maven build is better maintained (obviously!). I use the SBT build only for "playing around" and then I just use my brew-installed SBT, not the this one that's bundled (bungled more like it...).

UPDATE: the build script `build/sbt` is supposed to download the jar file on demand. I think someone built the tgz file with this bogus HTML file, without checking it first. I'm investigating and I'll file a bug report.

In the mean time, just delete the `build/sbt-launch-0.13.7.jar` and try running `build/sbt` again (`sbt/sbt` is obsolete and just calls `build/sbt`).

UPDATE2: Crap, deleting the file doesn't help. I was mistaken that the bogus jar file is included. I think the URLs are bad that it attempts to read from. Stand by...

FINAL UPDATE: The good news is this bug is fixed for 1.5. For now, just download `http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/sbt-launch/0.13.7/sbt-launch.jar`, move it to the `build` directory, and rename it `sbt-launch-0.13.7.jar`. Then `build/sbt` will work.

Comment: Can you please share the steps to install Spark using maven? Its not clear on their website.

Comment: I meant using the `mvn` command on the downloaded distribution. See http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/building-spark.html for details.

Comment: Sorry, i am a newbie. Can you tell me where is this build directory?

Comment: After you open the tgz file, the root directory will be `spark-1.4.1`. That's the directory which has the `build` subdirectory.

Comment: amazingly my directory doesn't have build directory... what's happening?

Comment: So it wasn't there in spark-1.1.1 but it is there in spark-1.4.1

Comment: Right. I was talking about 1.4.1. http://apache.claz.org/spark/spark-1.4.1/spark-1.4.1.tgz

Answer (score 1):

In the **build/sbt-launch-lib.bash** edit correspond line with following

```
if [ $(command -v curl) ]; then
  (curl --fail --location --silent ${URL1} > ${JAR_DL} ||\
   (rm -f "${JAR_DL}" && curl --fail --location --silent ${URL2} ${JAR_DL})) && \
   mv "${JAR_DL}" "${JAR}"
elif [ $(command -v wget) ]; then
  (wget --quiet ${URL1} -O ${JAR_DL} ||\
   (rm -f "${JAR_DL}" && wget --quiet ${URL2} -O ${JAR_DL})) &&\
    mv "${JAR_DL}" "${JAR}"
else
```

Then try again, run the sbt assembly command

```
sbt/sbt assembly
```

Comment: I came here because I faced this error on your blogpost on how to install APache Spark on Ubuntu. You may want to update the blog if possible...